# Web Traffic blocked to specific IP address

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have a strange problem.  I am trying to get to my Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) laptop web server out on the web and have been unable to do so for the past couple of days.  I called the hosting company and they told me they're seeing the websites and that I should check ISUP.me and put in my domains... and they are indeed up.

I then tried connecting from my wife's computer (also running Ubuntu) and was able to do so without problem.  I have tried Lynx, Firefox and Chromium to no avail.

I am able to connect to the IP address / website using squid proxy running on an Amazon EC2 box. Also... I am not able to connect to via a VirtualBox Windows 7 session on the Ubuntu box in question.

I've checked ufw which is inactive and iptables and everything is blank.  I'm not sure where else to check.

Comment: You did not provide enough information to provide a good answer as such the default advice applies get a new iso reburn it to the usb and reinstall the os.

Comment: Are you running fail2ban on your webserver? Check to see if you got banned.

Comment: Not with this client.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem after turning off the power on the UVerse router and keeping it off for more than an hour.  When it came back on I was able to connect to the webserver again with no problem.  Called and told client to do the same as he was still having problems after I reset.  He did the same and was able to connect shortly after.  Mystery solved? dunno.. but working now.. THanks everyone.